# Android binding data has 2 variable

Tags: android

Is it okay if my databinding xml has 2 variable

```
 <data>
    <variable
        name="mymodel"
        type="com.model.booking.Booking" />

 <variable
        name="mymodel"
        type="com.model.Remarks.Result" />
</data>
```

Comment: if both name and type are same why do you need 2 variables ?

Comment: sorry not same already updated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is okay to have more than one variable in data binding XML but. The class can be the same but the variable name must be different.